# Why is a single join query running twice when using nhibernate LINQ syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i just migrated to nhibernate 3 and an using the LINQ syntax.  I now have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<Team> team = Session.Query<Team>().Fetch(r=>r.Country);
```

so it will do an upfront join (as i need these child objects for each record.

It is running the join query but I pulled this up in the nhibernate profiler and it turns out that its running the query twice (same exact query).

Is this a bug in the new version of nhibernate or is there something that I am doing wrong?

Also, any suggestions for additional ways to debug this to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Fetch or joins.

You are assigning an `IQueryable` to team. Therefore, each time you enumerate it (iterate, get count, etc), it is executing the query.

To avoid this, append `.ToList()` to the call, so it's executed and converted to an in-memory list.

Comment: There is a reason behind nt donig a tolist. you would want to avoid eagerly loading objects right.. jsut load them when you need it.